# Is there any way to find the Node scalability time on Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) using Logs?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, logging, azure-aks

I want to find the Node scalability time on Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) using Logs.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with some assumptions.

This information is taken from [Azure AKS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/cluster-autoscaler#retrieve-cluster-autoscaler-logs-and-status) (consider getting familiar with it, it describes how to enable, where to look at and etc):

> To diagnose and debug autoscaler events, logs and status can be
> retrieved from the autoscaler add-on.
>
> AKS manages the cluster autoscaler on your behalf and runs it in the
> managed control plane. You can enable control plane node to see the
> logs and operations from CA (cluster autoscaler).

The [same cluster-autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler) is used across different platforms, each of them can have some specific setup (e.g. for [Azure AKS](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/cloudprovider/azure/README.md)). Based on it, logs should have events like:

```
status, scaleUp, scaleDown, eventResult
```

Comment: Hi @WytrzymałyWiktor, No, still I am not able to find the Node scalability time and docker image download time using Kusto query

Comment: @SaurabhSunil. Have you managed to follow steps above and see these events in console? Usage of Kusto Query Language is a different question. Or consider updating your current one properly. Also [avoid asking multiple questions in one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/39224)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have enabled 'cluster-autoscaling' on the AKS Cluster diagnostics settings to be sent to Log Analytics, you can run the below KQL query against the workspace. Replace "scale_up" with whatever string you are searching for.

```html
AzureDiagnostics
| where Category == "cluster-autoscaler"
| where log_s contains "scale_up"
| project TimeGenerated, log_s
| extend log_s
```